# Push and Unshift problems- Perl

Tags: perl

I am currently trying to add speech marks onto the start and end of a line which I have an edited from a CSV file and is currently stored in an array; I am currently trying to use push and unshift.

```
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;
use constant debug => 0;
use Text::CSV;

print "Running CSV editor......\n";

#my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";

my $fileextension = substr($file, -4);

#If the file is a CSV file then read in the file.
if ($fileextension =~ m/csv/i)
{   
print "Reading and formating: $ARGV[0] \n";

    open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

    my @fields;

    while (my $line = <$data>) 
    {       
    #Clears the white space at the end of the line.
    chomp $line;

    #Splits the line up and removes the <br />.
    my @lines = split qr{<br\s?/>}, $line;

    #Removes the control character.     
    shift (@lines); 
    print "\n";
    print $_,$/ for @lines;

    push (@lines, "\"");
    unshift (@lines, "\"");
```

When I try and use the final two lines it doesn't add anything onto the start and end.

Comment: Why aren't you using Text::CSV? How do you know the late two lines don't do anything? You don't do anything with the data after those lines. Why do you have a variable called `@lines` (plural) containing the split up parts of a single line?

Comment: You need a join to put it back into a single string

Comment: Please post real code, and a small sample of your input.

Comment: I am using Text::CSV I have now amended the code to include it...... I know it doesn't work as I am printing them out after those last two lines.......I am them containing the split up parts as I had a long string and I needed to split them up into certain parts.

Comment: This still doesn't compile. How can it be your full code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that the quotes aren't getting added to the array? Your syntax is correct, so they are definitely working. Try something like this.

```
my $newStr = join $/, @lines;
print $newStr;
```

and see what that prints, I bet the quotes will be there :)

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Perl, so trying to figure all of this out.